# Add response to each item for loop in node.js and postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, promise

I have an array of schools like this:

```
{
 "schools": [
            {
                "name": "S1",
                "id": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "S2",
                "id": 2
            },
            {
                "name": "S3",
                "id": 3
            }
        ]
}
```

and each school has schedule. To Get that I iterate the schools array in a promise and when I get the response I get an array like this

```
{
 "schools": [
            {
                "name": "S1",
                "id": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "S2",
                "id": 2
            },
            {
                "name": "S3",
                "id": 3
            }
        ],
"schedules": [
            [],
            [
                {
                    "id_schedule": 58,
                    "hour1": "13:00:00",
                    "hour2": "20:00:00",
                    "id_schools_schedule": 2
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "id_schedule": 59,
                    "hour1": "06:30:00",
                    "hour2": "22:30:00",
                    "id_schools_schedule": 3
                }
            ]
        ]
}
```

I want to know. how to asign the response of each item?
this is my code

```
for (var i =0; i < datosRes.schools.length; i++){
                array_horarios.push(ObtSchedule(datosRes.schools, i))
              }
              Promise.all(array_horarios).then(response => {
                datosRes.horarios = response;
                eq.local = data;
              }).catch(err => {
                return res.json(200,{"datos":datosRes});
              })

function ObtHorario(schools, i){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var id_school = schools[i].id;
    Mod_Schedule.obtSchedule(id_school,function(error, data){
      if(error || data.error){
        errorDB = {"error_log": error, "error_data": data.error};
        reject(errorDB)
      }else{
        resolve(data)
      }
    })
  })
}
```

What I am doing wrong?
I get the response but only I want to add to each item of schools the schedules

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First thing first:
You can send ONE response to ONE request. So your question to send multiple responses is invalid.

Here's what you can do, you can get the array of schools with their schedules.

If you are using MongoDB, here's what you can do:

Using [Aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) query:

```
db.schools.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {} // Your condition to match schools here
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
                      from:"schedules",
                      localField: id,
                      foreignField: id_schools_schedule,
                      as: "schedulesData"
                 }
    },
]);
```

Here, you will get data something like:

```
[
        {
            "name": "S1",
            "id": 1,
    "schedulesData": []
        },
        {
            "name": "S2",
            "id": 2,
    "schedulesData": [{
                "id_schedule": 58,
                "hour1": "13:00:00",
                "hour2": "20:00:00",
                "id_schools_schedule": 2
            }]
        },
        {
            "name": "S3",
            "id": 3,
    "schedulesData": [
            {
                "id_schedule": 59,
                "hour1": "06:30:00",
                "hour2": "22:30:00",
                "id_schools_schedule": 3
            }
        ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: I use Postgres my friend

Comment: I don't have hands-on experience on PostgreSQL but I am pretty sure, we would have similar functionality there as well.